# Using core data for objects that conform to a protocol

Tags: ios, core-data, protocols, nsmanagedobject

Multiple distinct entities in my model can be considered 'reviewable'. Any such reviewable entity can then be part of a `Review` object. I would usually model this using a `Reviewable` protocol for the different entities to conform to, and the `review` object could simply hold a reference to an object of type `id <reviewable>`.

How can this be handled and persisted by core data? I don't see a good way to model the relationship when defining my `Review` entity since I don't really have another entity to use as the destination - all I know is that it will be an `NSManagedObject` that conforms to `Reviewable`.

Will I need to use inheritance instead?

Answer (score 0):

Because relations in the object graph require a back link, which carries type implications, I have always had to solve this problem with inheritance to contain the forward relation. In your case, this would be the `Review` object.